# Http Basic AUTH Window not poping up

Tags: php, authentication, basic-authentication

This is my code

```
if (!($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] == 'admin' && $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'] == 'admin')) {
            header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Protected"');
            header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
            return new JsonResponse(array('error' => "Unauthorized: appel non authentifié ou détails d'authentification non valides"));
        }
```

It is not showing window to enter User/Pwd Window at all. I restarted browser and server but no difference.

**Update**

I am using Chrome. I want it pops up window every time and ask Login

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: Is your if condition true. Or have you tried without if ?

Comment: Have you checked the actual response sent by your server? Is the `401` status code actually being sent, or is it not output or somehow overridden by your web server?

Answer (score 0):

```html
<?php
if (!isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'])) {
    header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="My Realm"');
    header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
    echo 'Text to send if user hits Cancel button';
    exit;
} else {
    echo "<p>Hello {$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']}.</p>";
    echo "<p>You entered {$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']} as your password.</p>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, I know that, once it's logged in no matter what you do it never shows again. Question updated

Comment: Have you tried to unset the username and password? http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php

Comment: you mean unsetting `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']`?

Comment: Yes, and the PW

Comment: Ah - so on each request first I unset these two variables and then perform further.

Comment: That is the best practice, always make sure the variable is empty when you expect it is empty.

Comment: Ok Window is popped up, I enter user/pwd which are checked against DB. on wrong entry it should show again, so I just unset and send 401 header again right?

Comment: Now issue is, even if I enter correct credentials it does not go to else condition since I am unsetting it

Comment: Maybe first try to use some static user credentials. When the static one does work, you can blame the SQL Query. And maybe try to send a 200 header at success.